# VS no workspace on that server could be located

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online). I upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015. When I open my source control projects, I receive this error:

The solution you have loaded is bound to the source control server at https://xx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection, but no workspace on that
server could be located. If you do have a workspace on this server, and you want this solution to be opened under source control,
connect to that server using Team Explorer and then re-open the solution.
The active solution has been temporarily disconnected from source control because the server is unavailable.  To attempt to reconnect to source control, close and then re-open the solution when the server is available.  If you want to connect this solution to another server, use the Change Source Control dialog.

It appears VS 2015 has a setting to adjust. My workspace is stored locally. I have signed into Visual Studio Team Services with the proper account and my workspace folders are mapped. When I open VS 2013, it works fine. How do I enable source control mapping on VS 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the steps as the error message indicated:

> If you do have a workspace on this server, and you want this solution
>   to be opened under source control, connect to that server using Team
>   Explorer and then re-open the solution.

Open VS2015 and connect the project from Team Explorer. After you connected to the project, the work space you created in VS2013 should can be detected by VS2015 and the solution will be listed there. Then you can open the project from there.